# Can you use QWebView cookies/sessions with QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, cookies

I am making a program with a QWebView that shows the user pages from our site. At the same time I want to use QNetworkManager to make background HTTP requests to the site. Is there a way to share the user's cookies between the QWebView and QNetworkManager so that they just have one session? Right now the user can log in in the QWebView, but then when I make get() calls on the QNetworkManager object the site behaves as if the user is not logged in, although they are logged in in the QWebView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes. You can use [`QNetworkAccessManager::cookieJar()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkcookiejar.html#details) to get a handle of the `QNetworkCookieJar` that takes care of cookies for a given `QNetworkAccessManager`. You can set this cookie to many `WebViews`.

```
QWebView webView = new QWebView();
QNetworkCookieJar cookieJar = new QNetworkCookieJar();
QNetworkAccessManager nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
nam.setCookieJar(cookieJar);
webView.page()->setNetworkAccessManager(nam);
```